# Trying to add a space in Canada Postal code formatting for Report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a space in the formatting but when I run this select it will not add a space like this A#A #A# could someone help me out?

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', ''),0, Len(REPLACE(CONVERT(INT, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', '')-2)) + '  ' + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', ''), Len(REPLACE(CONVERT(INT, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', '')-2), Len(REPLACE(CONVERT(INT, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', '')))) as [Postal Code],
```

Currently I have these formats in the fields A#A-#A#, a#a #a#, A#A#A#, a#a#a#, a#a-#a#

Examples:
B1P5T9 B1A 3G4 B1P2R4 B1L1A2 B1P4L9 B1Y 3B7 B1P 1H6 B1L 1G9

Comment: You need to provide your database engine and sample values of the postal_code values as they are stored.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 please see above for formats.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41705169/edit) your question to include tags and examples in the question not in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, this code works regardless if you have a space or dash to start with. Will only add a space when needed. Will work with any format listed above also will put all to uppercase.

```
Left(UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code)), '-', ' ')), 
3)+' '+ Right(UPPER(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DECRYPTBYKEY(postal_code))), 3) as  [Postal Code],
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
select case
when charindex(' ', postal_code) = 4 
  and len(postal_code) = 7 then postal_code
when charindex(' ', postal_code) = 0  and len(postal_code) = 6 
  then left(postal_code, 3) + ' ' + right(postal_code, 5)
etc
else default value 
end formattedPostalCode

from etc
where it's Canadian
```